# Discord.py - Hi Command Need Fix

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a bot that when someone types $hi @(someone), it responds with hi @(member that was mentioned in the command).

Code:

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
    
client = discord.Client()
   
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
    
@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx, *,member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(member)
    bot.add_command(member, 'hi')
    
client.run(os.getenv("token"))
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0):

To mention a member you can use different functions.

Your function/command now does not work for me or is not giving out what you expect.

**Try out the following:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx, *, member : discord.Member = None):
    if member is None: # Optional
        await ctx.send("You did not mention a member") # Optional
    else:
        await ctx.send("Hi, {}".format(member.mention)) # We mention a member and send "Hi"
```

- Here we use `format(member.mention)` to mention the user and use `{}` as as our value to be filled (`member.mention`).
- If you do not want the Optional part just remove it.

Or a **second method:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx, *, member : discord.Member = None):
    if member is None: # Optional
        await ctx.send("You did not mention a member") # Optional
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Hi, {member.mention}!") # Use f-strings
```

- Here we used `f`-strings in order to make it "more" easy to write/code. It works like the method above but now we can insert a value into your brackets (`{member.mention}`) and do not have to separate it.
- If you do not want the Optional part just remove it.

*If you do not want the "Optional" part in both commands you can also remove the `= None` in `member : discord.Member`*

Comment: Hi, tnx but I still can't get it to respond not even whit You did not mention a member I can get it to respond if I use @client.event
async def on_message(message):
what else am I doing wrong I am using python 3.9 and bot has administrator

Comment: Why do you use `client` and `bot`? If you want to use `client.command` you have to use: `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")` - I assume you want to use that as `client.event` and `bot.command` do not make any sense together...